# Assembly and Manage Module .Net

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Could anyone shed a light on the example:
For example i have three simple project such like `MyProject.WEB, MyProject.BLL, MyProject.DAL`. Does .Net compiler create two managed modules for BLL and DAL and combine them into one assembly?
Thanks for helping me

Comment: You need to provide more context. But if those projects are dlls simply referencing each other then the answer is no. You have to go out of your way to compile to a netmodule (you can't do it from VS for example) and then you need to link them into an assembly (using al.exe, if memory serves). IF you have two netmodules you *can* combine them into a single assembly, but my guess is that's not what you have. There *are* tools that *can* merge assemblies into one such as ILMerge and ILRepack.

Comment: Use Visual Studio command line compiler : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(v=vs.80).aspx